# Ubuntu sees 2.0 ports as 1.1?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb, usb-modem, interface

I have an ASUS M5A78L-M LX V2 motherboard, the usb ports of which are all USB 2.0. I realised that my wireless USB card was working and connecting much faster connected to the front panel USB ports. Here is the syslog output when it is connected to the motherboard USB ports:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1269611/

It did connect eventually...

And here it is connected to the front panel:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1269619/

As you might have seen, the log shows that connected to the front panel, the usb is 2-x, while the back is 1-1.

`lsusb` while connected to front panel:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1269622/

`lsusb` while connected to MB ports:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1269622/

As you can see, lsusb thinks that 5 of my USB ports are USB 1.1. Even though I disable legacy USB in the BIOS.
When timed, the back panel took 18 seconds to detect the netwoork, while the front panel took, if not immediately, 1-2 secs to detect the network.

Sorry for the long post, all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... In any case the bug appears to be **fixed in Quantal stable**, although `lsusb` still reports five of my ports as 1.1.

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Oh wait, it's actually something in the bios... Not sure what though...

Answer (score 2):

As I can read in your Mobo manual you have settings there to slow down your USB speed. Did you check these settings? You can read how on your manual on page 2-16. Maybe you set them to slow speed mode?

Your manual you can find here:

[ASUS M5A78L-M LX V2](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/M5A78L-M-LX-V2/Manual/264317)

Comment: You mean hi-speed and full-speed settings? They are at full speed, I think. I will check in my Windows 8 install and see if the problem persists...

Comment: It says "USB 2.0 Controller Mode" and should be in there ... good luck.

Comment: I have it at high speed - this must be a Ubutu bug then...

Comment: So you checked in Windows 8 and it works at high speed?

Comment: I have been unable to tell whether Win 8 thinks it is USB 1/2, but there is definitely a boost in speed (immediate connection) when plugged into the back USB port (MB) as opposed to the back ports while running Ubuntu. Can I report a bug on these grounds? Although I may have a lack of evidence.

Comment: I have benchmarked an ext4 usb that I have on both the front and back panel ports, and the front panel was slower: front: min read: 11.4MB/s max read: 17.4Mb/s avg read: 16.7 avg access: 1.0ms back: min read: 12.1MB/s max read: 17.5mb/s avg read: 16.8mb/s avg access: 1.0ms

Comment: ... So it must be Ubuntu using a generic driver or somethiing... But it is really confusing why the flash drive is slower on the fronpanel, but the usb network card is faster on the front panel.??

Answer (score 1):

The top line of your log: "usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd" says a USB 2.0 device was connected to device 8 on bus 1-1. 1-1 doesn't refer to the type of connection. ehci is used for USB 2.0.

That leaves the speed question, of course. I had a motherboard that would give me all kinds of errors when I plugged a capture device in a particular port, but not when I plugged in others. The motherboard developed other problems, too, and when replaced that issue disappeared. Whether that's what happening your case, however, I don't know.

Looking at the point of delay, there is/was a recent bug [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815091).

If I were you I would physically turn my computer around and see if that made a difference in connection speed. I wonder if it is possible that the physical position of the wireless device is making a difference in how fast it can find and connect to access points.

Here are the lines demonstrating the slowdown:

Good:

`Oct  9 18:13:05 zheoff NetworkManager[879]:  Trying to remove a non-existant call id.

Oct  9 18:13:07 zheoff NetworkManager[879]:  Auto-activating connection 'virgin'`

Two second delay

Bad:

`Oct  9 18:06:42 zheoff NetworkManager[879]:  Trying to remove a non-existant call id.

Oct  9 18:07:04 zheoff NetworkManager[879]:  Auto-activating connection 'virgin'.`

22 second delay

Comment: In Windows 8 RP the back ports seem to be very fast, though I will benchmark an ext4 drive plugged into the back and front ports and see what happens...

Comment: Oddly enough, the front panel was slightly slower on read benchmarks... But why is it displaying as USB 1.1 on `lsusb`?

Comment: It's not. It's displaying the bus number as 1-1 and calling it a high speed device. In both cases it is assigning to an EHCI hub which is USB 2.0. For more information see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Enhanced_Host_Controller_Interface

Comment: What about ohci, what is that? It was shown up on lshw.

Comment: That's what your system would use if you plugged in a device that could only do USB version 1.0 or 1.1. But that's not what you are using for this device plugged in either place--looking at the syslog output you posted (your first two pastebin links). That says it is a high speed device. See the very top line of the your two syslog logs. The motherboard is capable of running a particular port against a different hub depending on the plugged in device's characteristics.

Comment: But the *hub* - the actual port is marked as ohci... And anyway, why is the network USB so slow.?

Comment: Your `lsusb` listings say that buses 3-7 are used for USB 1.0. Buses 1 and 2 are both mentioned as USB 2.0. I see evidence that you are connecting as USB 2.0 no matter if you connect to bus 1 or 2. I see no evidence that ohci is used for these devices, the top lines of the two /var/log excerpts say explicitly that ehci is being used for each device. I'm not saying you are wrong about your device being slow depending on where you plug it in, it _is_, that's also clear from the logs.

Comment: I've added something else to try to this answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6080/discussion-between-marcappuccino-and-john-s-gruber)